# Object not found with JPA query method but it exists in the DB

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I'm just trying to update a record in the DB from my spring boot application, but when I use a JPA query method to find the object by it's id, the object it's always empty

This is my repository interface, all the other queries works, except for that `Optional<Products> findById(Integer id);`

```
@Repository
public interface ProductsRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Products, Integer> {

    Page<Products> findAll(Pageable pageable);

    void save(Products product);

    Optional<Products> findById(Integer id);

    // ...
}
```

This is the piece of code in the service that calls the repo and it's causing me some problems

oldProduct it's always empty

```
//...
    Optional<Products> oldProduct = productsRepository.findById(productDto.getId());

    if (oldProduct.isEmpty()){
        return ResponseEntity.badRequest().body("Product with id: "+productDto.getId()+" not found.");
    }
//...
```

This is the productDto JSON, which is the object that contains the updated data, that I should write in the db at the end

```
{
    "id" : 1,
    "name" : "Taralli al peperoncino",
    "price" : 3.6,
    "quantity" : 15,
    "availableFrom" : "10/04/2023 00:00:00",
    "availableUntil" : "13/07/2023 00:00:00",
    "categoryId" : "8",
    "imageBase64" : ""
}
```

I tried to override the JPA method by doing this

```
@Query(value = "SELECT * FROM eshop_products where id=:id", nativeQuery = true)
    Optional<Products> findById(Integer id);
```

And it actually works, but I'd like to understand what the problem is to avoid it in the future, and maybe be able to use JPA as much as i can, especially with this basic queries

- Spring v3.0
- Java v17
- JPA latest (07/06/2023)

**SOLVED**

I don't know why, but today it's working
Maybe there was something in the chache that was cousing this problem, because I just added `spring.jpa.show-sql=true` and it worked perfectly with the JPA query method

Comment: Where's the entity mapping? You can also print the generated query and check it

Comment: could you post     Optional<Products> oldProduct = productsRepository.findById(productDto.getId());
 result in debug mode ?

Comment: @Mar-Z Optional has `isEmpty()` since java 11.

Comment: Please post the entity class

Comment: As well as the entity class, turn on SQL logging with parameter logging to see what is actually generated for your findById method. It probably isn't the same as the native query at all, possibly due to mismapping something, or a relationship join forcing an inner join to something that doesn't exist (check your not-null constraints on relationships)

Comment: Congratulations on solving this.

It may be prudent to see how your SQL statements are being structured. 

Enabling logging by doing:    logging.level.org.hibernate.SQL=DEBUG
logging.level.org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder=TRACE